# How to get Text from TextBox to ViewModel while it is bound to other control?(MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a simple app, that should add `SelectedItem` from ComboBox to ListBox.
I have `Model`:Player

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; }
    }
}
```

And ObservableCollection property in my ViewModel (Players)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayersInTournament { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    public ICommand AddPlayerCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {            
        DataAccess access = new DataAccess();
        Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>(access.GetPlayers());//GetPlayers from DataBase
        AddPlayerCommand = new RelayCommand(AddPlayer, CanAddPlayer);
    }

    private void AddPlayer()
    {
        //Something like PlayersInTournamen.Add(SelectedPlayer);
    }

    private bool CanAddPlayer()
    {
        bool canAdd = false;
        foreach(Player player in Players)
        {
            if (player.IsSelected == true)
                canAdd = true;
        }

        return canAdd;
    }
}
```

Property(`ItemSource`) of my ComboBox is bound to the `Players` collection. When the application is `Loaded` my `ComboBox` is filled with objects from DataBase and when I select one of them it is displayed in my `ReadOnly` `TextBox`. I achieved this by binding the `Text` property to the `ItemSelected.Name` property of `ComboBox`. There is an Add button in the app that add selected player to the tournament(`ListBox`)(the app is about tournament). `ListBox`'s `ItemSource` is PlayersInTournament collection(see in ViewModel).

XAML(DataContext of Window is set to ViewModel instance after InitializeComponents()):

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxDemoSQL.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxDemoSQL"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>   
        <RowDefinition/>   
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 40 0 10">

            <TextBox x:Name="HoldPlayerTextBox"
                     Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=PlayersComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"
                     IsReadOnly="True">
            </TextBox>

            <ComboBox Name="PlayersComboBox" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      Margin="10 0 0 0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      Text="Select player"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Content="Add" Margin="120 0 120 0"
                Command="{Binding AddPlayerCommand}"/>

        <ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding PlayersInTournament}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Photo to understand better:

[image]

So basically there are 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to add to the PlayersInTournament collection a
   player that is selected in `ComboBox` because I can't get the name
   of that Player from `TexBox`(because its' Text property is bound to
   another Property)
2. I don't know how to disable `Add Button`(CanAddPlayer method) when
   there is no Player selected, I tried by adding `IsSelected`(see
   Player model) property, but for it to work I have to bind to any
   property in View that would change it, but I don't know which
   property can be used for this thing.

ICommand implementation:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    private Action methodToExecute;
    private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest the following.

You can override the `ToString()` method of your Player class to ease display in your `ComboBox` e.g.:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

By default `ComboBox` binding will call the `ToString()` method of whatever property it is bound to.

If you bind `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to a new `Player` property in the ViewModel, you can clear the selected player text in the `ComboBox` from code in the ViewModel.

If you add a `CommandParameter` to your Button binding, you can pass the selected player instance to the command, but this isn't strictly needed once you have a bound property in your ViewModel.

Thus your XAML becomes something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="100"
          Text="Select player"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlayer}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"/>
<Button x:Name="ButtonAddPlayer" 
        Content="Add" 
        Command="{Binding AddPlayerCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPlayer}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="62,176,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="75"/>
```

And your ViewModel contains:

```
public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayersInTournament { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
private Player _selectedPlayer;

public Player SelectedPlayer
{
    get => _selectedPlayer;
    set => SetField(ref _selectedPlayer, value);
}

public ICommand AddPlayerCommand { get; set; }

private bool CanAddPlayer(object obj)
{
    return SelectedPlayer != null;
}
private void AddPlayer(object param)
{

    if (param is Player player)
    {
        PlayersInTournament.Add(player);
        Players.Remove(player);
        SelectedPlayer = null;
    };
}
```

Note that in the above code, as a player is added to the tournament list it is removed from the available players list preventing reselection of the same player.
Setting the `SelectedPlayer` property to `null` not only clears the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` display but also disables the `Add` button.

Also if you are likely to have several properties that you implement a helper function to handle your `INotifyPropertyChanged` events.

```
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CommandParameter` in xaml:

```
 <Button Content="Add" Margin="120 0 120 0"
         Command="{Binding AddPlayerCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source=PlayersComboBox}"/>
```

in your ViewModel:

```
    private ICommand _addPlayerCommand;
    public ICommand AddPlayerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addPlayerCommand== null)
            {
                _addPlayerCommand= new RelayCommand(param => OnAddPlayerClicked(param));
            }
            return _addPlayerCommand;
        }
    }
    private void AddPlayer(object param)
    {
        Player selectedPlayer = (player)param;
        PlayersInTournamen.Add(SelectedPlayer);
    }
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought about this, but relay command doesn't allow passing parameters, I should do what @ChirsBD said above, or change ICommand Implementation or find way to pass parameter to relay command

Comment: It allows passing parameter.  Did you notice this change : `_addPlayerCommand= new RelayCommand(param => OnAddPlayerClicked(param));`
I will include my RelayCommand implementation to my answear, it should work